# write.table doesn't separate content with tabs?

Tags: r

I am currently trying to modify a file, and then save it in R. 
The problem I am having is saving it, the content is not tab separated, which I am not sure I understand why?

This is the code:

```
phones <- read.table("/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/deltas/s5/data/lang/phones.txt", quote="\"")
ctm <- read.table("/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/deltas/s5/exp/align_test/phones.ctm", quote="\"")

names(ctm) <- c("file_name","prob","start","end","id")
ctm$file <- gsub("_[0-9]*$","",ctm$file_name)
names(phones) <- c("phone","id")


ctm2 <- merge(ctm, phones, by="id")
ctm3 <- ctm2[,-1]
ctm3 <- ctm3[,-5]
ctm3 <- ctm3[with(ctm3,order(ctm3$file_name , ctm3$start)),]
ctm4 <- ctm3[1:nrow(ctm3),1:ncol(ctm3)]
write.table(ctm4, "/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/deltas/s5/data/align_test/phones.txt",col.names = F , row.names=F, quote=F, sep="\t")
```

And the [`ctm4`](https://pastebin.com/ShW0D60W) is like this:

```
fbbh-b-an86 1   0   0.33    <SIL>
fbbh-b-an86 1   0.33    0.21    S_B
fbbh-b-an86 1   0.54    0.2 IY_E
fbbh-b-an86 1   0.74    0.16    Z_B
fbbh-b-an86 1   0.9 0.29    IY_E
fbbh-b-an86 1   1.19    0.21    D_B
fbbh-b-an86 1   1.4 0.34    IY_E
```

Why are some lines tab separated and others not.

The input being the [`ctm`](https://pastebin.com/RCfJ7XYF) in space separated as such

```
fbbh-b-an86 1 0.000 0.330 1
fbbh-b-an86 1 0.330 0.210 110
fbbh-b-an86 1 0.540 0.200 71
fbbh-b-an86 1 0.740 0.160 138
fbbh-b-an86 1 0.900 0.290 71
fbbh-b-an86 1 1.190 0.210 38
fbbh-b-an86 1 1.400 0.340 71
```

and [`phones`](https://pastebin.com/27b5LJTc) is also space separated as such:

```
<eps> 0
<SIL> 1
<SIL>_B 2
<SIL>_E 3
<SIL>_I 4
<SIL>_S 5
AA_B 6
AA_E 7
AA_I 8
AA_S 9
AE_B 10
```

So why is the output not tab separated, even though it is specified in the `write.table` that it should be separated with tabs?

Comment: Can you share these files? That would be easy to find the solution or the source of problem

Comment: Why do you say they're not tab separated? They seem to be

Comment: They are tab separated, aren't they? The difference is only that 0.000 is represented as 0 thus reducing line length.

Comment: at line 5.. there is space between the cols.

Comment: I've added the full files